# Shorten this jquery code involving onClick, addClass, and removeClass

Tags: jquery

I recently found some code on here that works great for me but I need to have 3 instances of it and I was wondering how I could shorten it. I tried using this and finding iframe but that didn't work for me

```
<div id="canvas1" class="flex-map">
    <iframe id="map_canvas1" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2988.340069842146!2d-81.6936185!3d41.496904799999996!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8830f07f1ec04a5b%3A0x13f658e62ff00665!2s230+W+Huron+Rd%2C+Cleveland%2C+OH+44113!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1427256282821" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="canvas2" class="flex-map">
    <iframe id="map_canvas2" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2988.340069842146!2d-81.6936185!3d41.496904799999996!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8830f07f1ec04a5b%3A0x13f658e62ff00665!2s230+W+Huron+Rd%2C+Cleveland%2C+OH+44113!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1427256282821" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="canvas3" class="flex-map">
    <iframe id="map_canvas3" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2988.340069842146!2d-81.6936185!3d41.496904799999996!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8830f07f1ec04a5b%3A0x13f658e62ff00665!2s230+W+Huron+Rd%2C+Cleveland%2C+OH+44113!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1427256282821" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#map_canvas1').addClass('scrolloff');
    $('#canvas1').on('click', function () {
        $('#map_canvas1').removeClass('scrolloff');
    });
    $("#map_canvas1").mouseleave(function () {
        $('#map_canvas1').addClass('scrolloff');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class and a single click/mouseleave handler

```
<div id="canvas1" class="flex-map canvas">
    <iframe id="map_canvas1" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2988.340069842146!2d-81.6936185!3d41.496904799999996!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8830f07f1ec04a5b%3A0x13f658e62ff00665!2s230+W+Huron+Rd%2C+Cleveland%2C+OH+44113!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1427256282821" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.canvas iframe').addClass('scrolloff').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).addClass('scrolloff');
    });
    $('.canvas').click('click', function (e) {
        $(this).find('iframe').removeClass('scrolloff');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b5d06ppw/1/)

Since you want to add/remove class from the `iframe` inside the canvas add a class `canvas` to all the div elements.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this help or not, but you can simplified your code using following code, try this first:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

  $('#map_canvas1, #map_canvas2, #map_canvas3').addClass('scrolloff');

  $(document).on('click','#canvas1, #canvas2, #canvas3', function () {
    $(this).find('iframe').removeClass('scrolloff');
  });

  $("#map_canvas1, #map_canvas2, #map_canvas3").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).addClass('scrolloff');
  });
});
```